# A variable is cannot be found in scope

Tags: scope

Friends,
Could you please explain to me why when I use string:
destinationVC.bmiValue = String (format: "% .1f", bmi)
Pops up error that bmi is cannot be found in scope? Swift just says it can't find bmi variable in the CalculateViewController class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsQsv.png)

But when I set the new bmiValue variable, the program works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPNa1.png)

How it comes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code and not images of code ...

Comment: You define your `var bmi` in one function and use it in another. Function definitions are only valid in the scope (in your case the scope is the function) where they are defined. If you need the same variable in multiple functions of the same class, define it at class level.

Answer (score 0):

I found that:
It's not allowed to jump from function to function directly, it appropriate needs to set var or let above list, after class line.

I hope this information would be useful for new others.